# Finding minimum from column value between group of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with six columns:

```
EKey ABC  XYZ DOB  My_Min Row_Num
---- ---- --- ---- ------ -------
101  AB10 123 1946   100     1    
103  AB10 123 1946   200     2    
201  TN10 456 1955   150     1    
220  TN10 456 1955   240     2    
216  TN10 456 1955    80     3    
214  TN10 456 1955    80     4
```

I want to compute a new column `Required_Min` which should have the values as shown below:

```
EKey ABC  XYZ DOB  My_Min Row_Num Required_Min
---- ---- --- ---- ------ ------- ------------
101  AB10 123 1946   100     1    100
103  AB10 123 1946   200     2    100
201  TN10 456 1955   150     1     80
220  TN10 456 1955   240     2     80
216  TN10 456 1955    80     3     80
214  TN10 456 1955    80     4     80
```

Im using SQL for this, i.e., SSMS. Please help.

Comment: I'd suggest making a view to query your table and then add the column `Required_Min` to that view.

Comment: So what is the question? You do not know how to add a column to a table?

Comment: So I can add table by using ALTER TABLE statement but Im not sure how to get the right value in it.. I have updated the table for better understanding

Comment: My purpose is to get Min(My_Min) using  from group of rows in column Row_Num

Answer (score 0):

You can `JOIN` the table back to itself using the `MIN` aggregate:

```
select t.ekey, t.abc, t.xyz, t.dob, t.my_min, t.rownum,
   t2.required_min
from yourtable t
   join (
      select ekey, min(my_min) required_min
      from yourtable
      group by ekey
   ) t2 on t.ekey = t2.ekey
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming ssms implies sql server. I'm assuming that you want the minimum "my_min" from rows with the same "RowNum"
try this:

```
update table_name as outer
   set outer.Required_Min = (select min(My_Min) 
      from table_name as inner 
      where inner.RowNum = outer.RowNum)
```

---

-edit-

new assumption: ABC+XYZ+DOB form a natural key:

```
update table_name as outer
   set outer.Required_Min = ( select min(My_Min) 
      from table_name as inner 
      where inner.ABC = outer.ABC
      and inner.XYZ = outer.XYZ
      and inner.DOB = outer.DOB )
```

Comment: what columns make up the unique key that you wish to group by for the minimums? ABC+XYZ+DOB ?

Answer (score 0):

If your uniqueness is based on ABC+XYZ+DOB, you can do the following:

```
with TableMin as
(select ABC,XYZ,DOB,min(My_min) as My_min
group by ABC,XYZ,DOB
from Table1)
update t1 set t1.Required_Min=tm.My_min
from Table1 t1 inner join TableMin tm on t1.ABC=tm.ABC and t1.XYZ=tm.XYZ and t1.DOB=tm.DOB
```

But this join is quite hard for server with big amount of data. If ABC+XYZ in unique key (or even ABC), use this instead of full ABC+XYZ+DOB.

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable responses.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired results:

```
select EKey         = t.EKey    ,
       ABC          = t.ABC     ,
       XYZ          = t.XYZ     ,
       DOB          = t.DOB     ,
       My_Min       = t.My_Min  ,
       Row_Num      = t.Row_Num ,
       Required_Min = min(t.My_Min) over( partition by t.ABC , t.XYZ , t.DOB )
from dbo.my_table t
order by t.ABC     ,
         t.XYZ     ,
         t.DOB     ,
         t.Row_Num
```

If you actually want to add a new column to the table, then you'll need to do something like this:

```
alter table dbo.my_table add column Required_Min int null
go

update dbo.my_table
set Required_Min = s.Required_Min
from dbo.my_Table t
join ( select ABC , XYZ , DOB , Required_Min = min(My_Min)
       from dbo.my_table
       group by ABC , XYZ , DOB
     ) s on s.ABC = t.ABC
        and s.XYZ = t.XYZ
        and x.DOB = t.DOB
go

alter table dbo.my_table alter column Required_Min int not null
go
```

The `update` could also be standard SQL, using a correlated subquery instead of a derived table. Assuming decent indexing, the execution plans shouldn't vary too much:

```
update dbo.my_table
set Required_Min = ( select min(My_Min)
                     from dbo.my_table x
                     where x.ABC = dbo.my_table.ABC
                       and x.XYZ = dbo.my_table.XYZ
                       and x.DOB = dbo.my_table.DOB
                   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for analitical func PARTITION BY:

```
select EKey, ABC, XYZ, DOB, My_Min, Row_Num, 
  min(My_Min) OVER (PARTITION BY ABC, XYZ, DOB) as Required_Min
from Stats
```

Also, I recommend you to do not store 'Required_Min' as a column, but compute it on demand in a view or query. Otherwise, you'll have to spend your time on providing data relevance (triggers or smth ). So, I would build specific inedexes instead to improve query perfomance.